# Editing globals inside of a jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQUERY to parse a XML file, while at it, I'm writing into multipple arrays. Now my big troubles is to pass the results of the arrays outside the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//....
var ProjectList = new Array();

var N = 0;
var ID = [];
var A = [];


$.get("urlaub.xml", function(GetList) {

    $(GetList).find("u").each(function() {

        var $U = $(this);
        ID.push($U.attr("id"));
        $(this).A.push($U.find("A").text());


        N++;

    });

    alert(N); //not 0!        
});

alert(N); //allways 0
// ......​​​    
</script>
```

So, I need to find a method to make the arrays and the variable N accessable from outside, and im failing at it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The outside scope does not and will not have access to that data until after the request is complete. Place all code that needs that data inside the callback to `$.get`.

Comment: use var ProjectList = []; not new Array();

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already editing the globals, you just aren't waiting long enough to use them. For example,

```
//....
var ProjectList = [];

var N = 0;
var ID = [];
var A = [];


var getRequest = $.get("urlaub.xml", function(GetList) {

    $(GetList).find("u").each(function() {

        var $U = $(this);
        ID.push($U.attr("id"));
        $(this).A.push($U.find("A").text()); // what is .A? *confused*


        N++;

    });


});

getRequest.done(function(){
    alert(N); //not 0!  
});

alert(N); //always correctly 0 because we haven't received xml yet
// ......​​​
```

Comment: You can also use `return N;` + `pipe()` instead of `done()` which may be a bit nicer (and remove global `N` at all)